# Interfacing with Nichrome heater

Tags: microcontroller, relay, solid-state-relay, heat

I'm using Nichrome wire for a heating application and just using some scavenged parts from a slow cooker.  What would be the easiest way to turn on/off the Nichrome?  I'm thinking of just having a microcontroller switch 120VAC via a solid state relay (SSR) which would feed the Nichrome wire directly.

Is there any inductance issues I need to worry about?  The nichrome is just one long strip and not coiled in any way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think triacs are the normal semi conductor, maybe the one in the solid state relay.  In any case inductance is not much of an issue.  If the current rating of the ssr is ok and so is the isolation voltage ( 200 volts would be good ) I think you can go ahead.